# Unable to load redirected URL in UIWebview while loading through loadHTMLString

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

there is a url that gets redirected to another url when loaded in web,
now if i request that url i get html content and then i load that html content in uiwebview, but it doesn't get redirected to other url.
 redirected url is not received in delegate method shouldStartLoadWithRequest

Comment: Can you post some code what you have tried

Comment: Did you solve this?